# Rails, NGINX, Unicorn and Capistrano: Missing `secret_token`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, environment-variables, unicorn

I have deployed my Rails 4.2.0 app into a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS using NGINX, Unicorn and Capistrano. Everything works fine except by the missing of my secret_key_base in production environment.

Here is my secrets.yml production block:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["APP1_SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

In my ~/.bashrc in the server I have:

```
export APP1_SECRET_KEY_BASE=token
```

It's all ok with the variable:

```
deployer@euler:~$ echo $APP1_SECRET_KEY_BASE
token

deployer@euler:~$ irb
2.2.0 :001 > ENV["APP1_SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
 => "token"
2.2.0 :002 > exit
```

But when I try to access my app I get the error in the log/unicorn.log:

```
ERROR -- : app error: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)
```

Seems to me that the Unicorn cannot access those values. So I have tried to use the [NGINX Env functionality](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env), but again no success, tried both ways in my nginx.conf:

```
env APP1_SECRET_KEY_BASE;
```

and

```
env APP1_SECRET_KEY_BASE=token;
```

But again, no success. The configuration passes the nginx start but the app doesn't work.

I even tried to use the dotenv gem, but no success also.

Any tip of what may be happening?

Comment: Is it not an option to just have the key hard coded in secrets.yml rather than in your bashrc? In my experience that's the best way to go (just make sure and add secrets.yml to your gitignore).

Comment: Maybe you are editing the wrong file (~/.bashrc), I think your web server don't use that for his environment. Maybe "editing /etc/default/unicorn and insert the export lines into it." source: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/unicorn-not-reading-environment-variables-correctly  Nilandnull and I (response below) didn't noticed you are using unicorn. sorry. Just tring to help.

Comment: how did you solve it? having this problem now?

Comment: @MichaelKMadison Can you read this article? https://gist.github.com/fschuindt/f5e2830566aa7e6b0942 I wrote it myself. There I make the setup of two Rails apps and I do in the right way that avoids this problem. I can explain it here but I think it's more detailed there.

Comment: @fschuindt thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

In /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

add the variables you need using:

passenger_env_var VARIABLE_NAME "value";

Comment: Do you noticed that I am using Unicorn instead of Passenger? (Even after about one month I am still facing this problem, sad)

Comment: Even knowing that I am not using Passenger, I have tried and got this error: 2015/03/30 13:41:55 [emerg] 2389#0: unknown directive "passenger_env_var" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dotenv-rails` gem to accomplish this. Have a file in your `shared` directory on your server called `.env` and copy it into the `current` directory on deploy.

That file would have some content like this:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=6c073f07...
```

The other benefit of using `dotenv-rails` is that if your application requires any other environment configuration you now will have a place for it.